# Why dropdown not showing the value during the Edit time

Tags: angularjs

Here when i click on Edit button why drpdown not display value

```
 <select ng-model="emp.C_Id" ng-options="I.C_Id as I.C_Name for I in CountryList">
```

**ctrl.Js**
Here ee.C_Name fetching the value & assign to  $scope.emp.C_Id but why dropdown not display that value

```
 $scope.EditBtn = function (ee) {
        var Editser = MyService.GetEditData(ee.EmpD_Id);
 Editser.then(function () {
            $scope.emp = {};
            $scope.emp.E_Name = ee.Emp_Name;
            $scope.emp.C_Id = ee.C_Name;
```

Comment: can you please add the full code snippet for the controller and service and view related to this problem?

Comment: `$scope.emp.C_Id = ee.C_Id;` instead of `$scope.emp.C_Id = ee.C_Name;`